# Add salt to data to be encrypted?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

Suppose a small amount of data is being encrypted with AES using a 256 key / IV.  The data encrypted could be known.  For example:

`abcdefghijklmno|axXXyyYY343433553353afsafaadfafdfsafsf|2013-01-01T00:00:00`

The first two parts (if you break the data on the pipe character) rarely change. the last part, a date / time does change but not often.  I've noticed that varying the date but not the first part of the message results in a cypher text which starts out the same all the time, presumably because the plain text is the same to start off.

Does this open me up to any kind of attacks against the encryption algorithm?  Would I gain anything by prepending a salt value to the beginning of the plain text?

I'm using the `AesManaged` class to generate the IV / Key and encrypt / decrypt the plain text, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to generate the key/IV.

Comment: @Iridium The Key / IV are generated by using the AesManaged class and calling the GenerateIV and GenerateKey methods, but they were both fixed.  An answer below showed me that the IV should be changed for each message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this problem, normally the IV is generated randomly for each cypertext and prepended not encrypted to the encrypted data. In this way every encrypted data is different from the others.

In code it should be

```
string str = "abcdefghijklmno|axXXyyYY343433553353afsafaadfafdfsafsf|2013-01-01T00:00:00";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
byte[] key = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }; // Your random key, I hope more random!

byte[] encrypted;

// Encrypt

using (var am = new AesManaged())
using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    am.Key = key;

    var iv = new byte[am.BlockSize / 8];
    rng.GetBytes(iv);
    am.IV = iv;

    using (var encryptor = am.CreateEncryptor())
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

        using (var encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            encStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
    }
}

// Decrypt

string str2;

using (var am = new AesManaged())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
{
    am.Key = key;

    var iv = new byte[am.BlockSize / 8];
    ms.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
    am.IV = iv;

    using (var decryptor = am.CreateDecryptor())
    using (var decStream = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        decStream.CopyTo(ms2);

        str2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms2.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms2.Length);
    }
}
```

Note that in general IV reuse cause a weakness in encryption. See for example the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation):

> For CBC and CFB, reusing an IV leaks some information about the first block of plaintext, and about any common prefix shared by the two messages. For OFB and CTR, reusing an IV completely destroys security.[6]

Comment: Is it necessary to write the IV into the stream?  I would assume the .Net AES class takes care of that since you set the IV property on it.  If its unique for each message, does the IV need to be kept secret, or is it like a salt and assumed that it will be discovered?

Comment: You can write it in the stream. It doesn't need to be kept secret. Net classes don't write it in the stream because there is no fixed standard on where to write it.

Comment: From the wiki I quoted before: "An initialization vector has different security requirements than a key, so the IV usually does not need to be secret"

Comment: I wonder what the purpose of setting the IV when encrypted / decrypting is then.  My understanding from the Wiki link is that the IV would be written first before the message so that the first block is not the same for the same plain text.

Comment: @Andy Exactly that. With equal IV (or with no IV), same plain text = same ciphered text. With IV, same plain text = different ciphered text, and even having the two IV you can't find that the two plain text are the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the primary purposes of the IV.  You should generate a random IV for each message that you send (if you're already doing that, something must be wrong in your code).

Answer (score -3):

AES256 should mix data in blocks of 256 bits (32 bytes). Since you have a long leading text (>32 bytes) that rarely changes you will have poor performance using encryption method. You can fix this but beginning the plaintext string with something that changes frequently as long as it changes within the first 32 bytes. You can do this be creating some random seed and actual useful data.

The purpose of seeding is so that "known" strings will not generate recognizable patterns once encrypted. This is the exact problem you will have, so you need to seed you data or at least use volatile data near the beginning of your plaintext.

EDIT:
I saw I had a negatives and wondered why. First, by performance I was intending to refer to the quality of the encryption, not execution time. And I accidentally said seed when I meant salt. A minor mistakes, but I see why the negatives. I am leaving my answer because it is the only once that explains (or at attempts to explain) that the salt (or at least something) that changes frequently really needs to appear with the 32 bytes plaintext block fed to AES-256. Salting is usually required if your encrypted data is subject to dictionary attacks (such as passwords), which seem unlikely for the OP, but your encrypted data should never be "predictable", which is why the OP should salt with data within the first 32 bytes.

Comment: Poor performance should not be a concern here, at least not before security. It is certainly not true that repeating plaintext results in worse performance than changing data (why should it?). The term seed (or seeding) is commonly used for pseudo random number generators (CSPRNG), not for encryption algorithms. Using volatile data - another unused term for encryption - is not enough for CBC encrypted data, it must be indistinguishable from random.